# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE_ENCODING] The value "./ab.txt" is invalid for option "encoding"

Tags: node.js, express

```
const fs=require('fs');

var read = fs.createReadStream(__dirname,'./ab.txt','utf8');
read.on('data',function(chunk){
  console.log("New Chunk Received ");
  console.log(chunk);
});
```

I am using fs module in the express app and trying to read the text file but command prompt is giving me the below error.

> internal/fs/utils.js:41
>       throw new ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE_ENCODING(encoding);
>       ^
>
> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE_ENCODING]: The value "./ab.txt" is
>   invalid for option "encoding"

Comment: Were you able to fix? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like the problem here is the fs function params

You are passing './ab.txt' as the 2nd parameter, which is taking that as the encoding.

This should work:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const read = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname,'./ab.txt'));
read.on('data',function(chunk){
  console.log("New Chunk Received");
  console.log(chunk);
});
```

'utf-8' is the standard encoding that fs goes for, so no need to pass this either.

Comment: Thanks. Real life-saver!